# How create a bash script with another bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm creating a bash script that will run only once, but after that, it'll create another bash script. I've tried to use CAT EOT, but the problem is that, instead of copy/paste the text inside the new bash, it "executes" all variables inside.

E.g.: instead of write "`date=$(date +%d)`", it is writing "`date=18`" in the new archive.

How can I make it copy/paste, instead of execute the command?

Comment: It's called a **bash script** or just **script**, not a **bash**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent variables from being expanded in a here-doc, put quotes around the token.

```
cat <<'EOT'
This is a here-doc
that contains $variable
EOT
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!!!